Hypergeometric Function Integration Using Mellin-Barnes Representation
I have the following integral:
$$
I=\int_0^1 d \alpha d \beta d \gamma r(\gamma) s(\alpha, \beta) T(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)
$$
where I define
$$r(\gamma)=(\gamma(1-\gamma))^{ -1 / 2+\epsilon / 2}$$
and,
$$s(\alpha, \beta)=\alpha(1-\alpha) \beta (1-\beta)$$
and,
$$
T(\alpha, \beta, \gamma)=(\gamma \alpha(1-\alpha)+(1-\gamma) \beta(1-\beta))^{-7 / 2+\epsilon / 2}
$$
I integrated over $\gamma$ using Mathematica, which resulted in:
ArgHeq6d3[α_, β_, γ_, ε_] := (γ (1 - γ))^(-(1/2) + ε/2) *
  (γ α (1 - α) + (1 - γ) β (1 - β))^(-(7/2) + ε/2) *
  α (1 - α) β (1 - β);

IntHeq6d3 = Integrate[ArgHeq6d3[α, β, γ, ε], {β, 0, 1}] // FullSimplify

The output is expressed in terms of the hypergeometric function ${}_2F_1$:
(2^-ε (-1 + α) α (-((-1 + β) β))^(1/2 (-5 + ε)) 
 Gamma[-(ε/2)] Gamma[(1 + ε)/2] Hypergeometric2F1[(7 - ε)/2, (1 + ε)/2, 
 1 + ε, -(((α - β) (-1 + α + β))/((-1 + β) β))] 
 Sin[(π ε)/2])/Sqrt[π]

However, Mathematica is unable to directly integrate in $\alpha$ and $\beta$. I followed steps of the Posted Answer for my own integral. To proceed, I used the Mellin-Barnes representation for the hypergeometric function ${}_2F_1$:
(* Contour Integral Formula of the Mellin-Barnes Representation *)
ConIntForm[a_, b_, c_, s_, z_] := 
 Gamma[c]/(2 Pi I Gamma[a] Gamma[b] Gamma[c - a] Gamma[c - b]) *
  Gamma[s] Gamma[c - a - b + s] Gamma[a - s] Gamma[b - s] (1 - z)^-s;

(* Defining the integrand and replacing the right parameters of Eq. B1 *)
EqB1Rep[α_, β_, ε_, s_] := 
 (-1 + α) α (-((-1 + β) β))^(1/2 (-5 + ε)) *
 ConIntForm[(7 - ε)/2, (1 + ε)/2, 1 + ε, 
 s, -(((α - β) (-1 + α + β))/((-1 + β) β))];

(* Integration Over Alpha and Beta *)
EqB1Int[ε_, s_] := Integrate[EqB1Rep[α, β, ε, s], {β, 0, 1}, 
{α, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> {ε > 0}] // FullSimplify

I define the result as:
(*Redefine the result*)
ResEqB1Int[\[Epsilon]_, 
  s_] = -((
   4 I Sqrt[\[Pi]] (-1 + s) (-5 + 
      2 s + \[Epsilon]) Cos[(\[Pi] \[Epsilon])/2] Csc[\[Pi] s] Gamma[
     1 + \[Epsilon]/2] Gamma[
     1/2 (1 - 2 s + \[Epsilon])] Gamma[-3 + 
      s + \[Epsilon]] Sec[\[Pi] s + (\[Pi] \[Epsilon])/
      2])/((-5 + \[Epsilon]) (-3 + \[Epsilon]) (-1 + \[Epsilon]) \
Gamma[5/2 - s] Gamma[-1 + s + \[Epsilon]/2] Gamma[-(5/2) + (
      3 \[Epsilon])/2])) // FullSimplify

And its inverse:
(*Inverse Mellin Transform with Simplified Assumptions*)
EqB1Transf[ε_] = 
 Assuming[ε > 0, 
  InverseMellinTransform[2  Pi  I*ResEqB1Int[ε, s], s, 1]]

Mathematica performs the integration, but is unable to compute the inverse (last result). I am wondering if it is possible to approach this calculation differently to complete the inverse Mellin-Barnes representation or perhaps another method would be more suitable. Any insights would be appreciated.

One way to proceed is to analyze the integrand to see if you can move the contour all the way to the left or right in the complex plane, and use the residue theorem to obtain it as a sum of pole contributions. See, for example, Integral Evaluation Using the Mellin Transform and Generalized Hypergeometric Functions: Tutorial and Applications to Antenna Problems (https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4020394). This is a standard tool, and I thinkk Mathematica uses it to do many integrals.

I'm trying to copy the expression for ResEqB1Int[ ] so I can work with it, but get unbalanced delimiters - could you check it?

@TomDickens it seems someone edited the code. I fixed it now.

@EverlinMartins the code was not edited. I just wrote the Greek letters properly to improve readability

What Range: ε is the parameter.Is Real,Complex or Integer ?

@MariuszIwaniuk It is a real parameter such that $\varepsilon>0$ (it can be thought of as a small parameter too)

@bmf Well, it works in Mathematica now after Everlin edited it...

@MariuszIwaniuk What about $\epsilon>1$? Sometimes Mathematica gives the correct answer for a different value of $\epsilon$.

You need to specify it better because for: $0\leq \epsilon \leq 1$ triple integral does not converge on {0,1}.  .I have Only solution for: $\epsilon >1$ and $\epsilon \in \mathbb{Z}_{>, 0}$(PositiveIntegers)

@MariuszIwaniuk if you set those conditions in Assumptions, does it return any result?
